# Display alert dialog on "a" click doesn't work

Tags: jquery, html

I'm trying to get the ID of the clicked element using jQuery but it isn't working. This is the jQuery code:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $("a.step").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });
});
</script>
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<ul class="circle" id="categories">
    <li><a id="option_6" class="step" href="#">Cat2</a></li>
    <li><a id="option_7" class="step" href="#">Cat3</a></li>
</ul>
```

What is wrong in my code?

**UPDATE**

I don't know the cause but I get out the `<script>...</script>` code out of `<body>` tags and write it in a `common.js` and now it works :-O

Comment: nothing: http://jsfiddle.net/9B9Wm/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/bfVyF/

Comment: Do you want the id of the `ul` element?

Comment: @cfs no, I want the id of the a element this is rare in my code doesn't work and jQuery is included

Comment: @Reynier did you see the posted fiddles? Do they work as you would expect?

Comment: Do you have other event listeners that are assigned before this one? They could be returning `false` which would prevent the execution of other handlers.

Comment: @JasonP yes I see and yes it works so my code is rigth just don't find the  cause why isn't working on my development, firebug console doesn't generate errors, I'm lost

Comment: What "isn't working"? Are you seeing the alert?

Comment: Probably a real basic question, but did you include jquery.js file before your script?

Comment: @Reynier : check if jQuery.js is included in code.

Comment: I get out the script of the `body` and leave in a .js file and it's working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you are trying to get the ID of the a-Link, but the aprent li has the id. ;)

so try `$(this).parent('li').attr('id')`

Comment: Not quite, the id attribute actually is on the anchor tag. The parent `<li>` has nothing. It may look like that at first glance since its all pretty close together, and its easy to miss the `<a`.

Answer (score -3):

Try getting rid of the extra function...

```
<script>
    $("a.step").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        alert(id);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: That would just break it if the anchor isn't already on the dom.

Comment: That function wrapper is a best practice for jQuery, it ensures that your code only runs after the DOM is ready to be manipulated